# USB-C to USB-C cable Arduino is not responding even not powered by this cable

Tags: serial, arduino-nano, power, usb, port-mapping

Hi I want to connect arduino NANO to my laptop with Type-C (USB-C) ports (on below image left side [4] and other side [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0Okp.jpg)). Now I bought a USB-C to USB-C cable, because it appeared to be the right tool, but the Arduino is not even powered by this cable. if I use regular USB 3.2 Gen 2 Port (on below image [5]) everythings for fine. but this usb-c ports not recognize the Arduino NANO even NANO's power LED is not switching ON.

On the other hand If I plug in my phone to this usb-c cable it works both ports. It means that cable is working good. I have changed 2 times cable stil not responding.

On the [docs](https://www.manua.ls/msi/gs66-stealth/manual?p=18), it look usb-c and regular usb 3.2 ports works same. But why usb-c ports not working with Arduino. also my laptop is MSI GS66

[image]

[image]

I'd appreciate if anyone has a solution or an idea to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe that port does only provide power if you draw enough power from it (like powerbanks often do). When the power LED isn't on but the Arduino works with a USB3 to USB-C cable from another port the problem is not with the Arduino. You can verify the absence of power by measuring the voltage between 5V and ground.

Comment: does Arduino Nano have a USB-C connector?

Comment: @jsotola https://urun.n11.com/arduino-urunleri-ve-setleri/type-c-cikisli-yeni-nesil-arduino-nano-type-c-kablo-hediyeli-P508671734

Comment: @jsotola Not the official Nanos, but there are many clones that do have USB-C.

Comment: @chrisl just because it has a USB-C connector, it does not mean that it has the circuitry to make it a USB-C interface

Comment: The pair of 5.1K resistors (CC1/CC2 pull-downs) seen in their product picture constitute the only extra circuitry a type C connector requires over the original  Nano's mini-B.  For C to C it's important that CC1/CC2 are doing their job because the negotiate the direction of the connection. For an A to C cable CC1 and CC2 and their resistors go unused. What I'm getting from this is that CC1/CC2 are failing to be pulled to GND, because one of the board/connector/jack are bad. If one (but not both) of the CC# lines are bad, rotating the cable 180 degrees would switch to the good CC#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That Nano is not USB-C compliant. Yes, it has the connector, but it doesn't do all the required handshaking to put the USB-C port on the laptop into host (and provide power) mode. This is needed because those ports are also power inputs and have to be told to output power - otherwise plug in power to them and bang horrible things happen.

You have to use the larger USB 3.2 ports which are always power providers and never power consumers.

Comment: I understood. thanks. you mean if I use usb-c to usb-b converter cable arduino uno should work. or  usb-c to mini usb can work original nano.